# Execute program after receiving webhook

Tags: php, webhooks, zendesk

I have to update two ticketing systems and make sure that when one its updated the other one is as well (Zendesk and Cherwell) , I plan on using ngrok running locally on the company server to recieve the webhooks. Then execute a script in to add a ticket with the recieved information in the other platform. What would I use as trigger to execute this script?

Comment: what script.. ?

Comment: The script is not the problem, the problem is getting it to run when a webhook is recieved

Comment: you can create a trigger for the ticket is updated in "meet all conditions". And action should be "notify target" and select the trigger.